# Position relative. Why it doesn't work?

Tags: html, css

[image]

Hello, I have a problem with relative positioning divs in another parent div. 
Why "am" is not under "b1", "b2", "b3"?

How to do it?

I wish "am" was under "b1", "b2", "b3"?

HTML:

```
<div id="eq2">
    <div id="bless12" class="male">b1</div>
    <div id="bless22" class="male">b2</div>
    <div id="bless32" class="male">b3</div>
    <div id="helmet2" class="EQ" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">h</div>
    <div id="atack2" class="male">at</div>
    <div id="balance2" class="male">ba</div>
    <div id="block2" class="male">bl</div>
    <div id="amulet2" class="EQ" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">am</div>
    <div id="armor2" class="EQ" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">a</div>
    <div id="legs2" class="EQ" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">l</div>
    <div id="boots2" class="EQ" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">b</div>
    <div id="shield2" class="EQ" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">s</div>
    <div id="ring2" class="EQ" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">r</div>
    <div id="weapon2" class="EQ" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">w</div>
    <div id="book2" class="EQ">bo</div>                   
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#eq2 {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
    width: 150px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 100px;
    bottom: 0px;
    border-right: 2px ridge;
    border-bottom: 2px ridge;
}
#eq2 div.EQ {
    width: 42px;
    height: 50px;
}
#eq2 div.male {
    width: 14px;
    height: 25px;
}

#eq2 div {
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: the css is essentially useless without the html it applies to.

Comment: First, this isn't JavaScript, it's CSS. Second, post all of your code that is relevant (HTML) and third, what is the specific problem you are having?

Comment: Edited. I added the rest of the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because

```
<div id="helmet2" class="EQ" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">h</div>
```

is coliding with

```
<div id="amulet2" class="EQ" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">am</div>
```

as you can see in your image because they use the same class EQ.

You could try to use different divs for each segment from top to bottom which are overlapping.